# jQuery - Display quantity in Cart instead of adding item again

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm building an order page in a Rails app and I'm using CoffeeScript and jQuery to display the Product selected in a shopping cart.  When I click on a radio button for the Product and select Add to Cart, the Product name and price display in the Cart.  If I click Add to Cart again, the Product is added on a new line.  I want to instead show the Product name as such:

(2) Twin Mattress $700

order.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $("input:radio").change(->
    if $(this).prop("checked", true)
      price = "<b>#{$(this).data('price')}</b>"
      dimensions = "<b>#{$(this).data('dimensions')}</b>"
      $("#product_details").html("#{price}#{dimensions}")


  )


  $("#add_to_cart").click((e)->
    e.preventDefault()
    $cart = {}
    $input = $("input:radio:checked")
    $label = $("label[for='#{$input.attr("id")}']")
    $form = $('#new_order')
    product_id = $input.val()
    $hidden_input = "<input type='hidden' name='#{$input.attr('name')}' value='#{product_id}' />"
    $form.prepend($hidden_input)

    $("#cart").append("#{$label.text()}<br/>")

    $.each($form.find("input:hidden"), (index, value) ->
      $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace(/\d+/g, index))
    )
  )
```

_form.html.erb

```
[<%= render partial: "error_messages", locals: { object: @order } %>
<div class="shopping-experience">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li>
          <%= f.fields_for :line_items do |ff| %>
            <% products.each do |product| %>
              <%= ff.label :product_id, product.name, for: "order_line_items_attributes_0_product_id_#{product.id}" do %>
                <span><%= product.name %> <%= price_of(product) %></span>
              <% end %>
              <%= ff.radio_button :product_id, product.id, data: { price: price_of(product), dimensions: product.dimensions } %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="shopping-cart">
        <div id="product_details"></div>
        <p><%= link_to 'Add To Cart', '#', id: 'add_to_cart' %></p>
        <div id="cart"></div>

        <p><%= f.submit 'Checkout' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>][1]
```

Comment: I have done something similar. I have seen that you use this $("#cart").append("#{$label.text()}<br/>") to add to your cart. You can use jquery and when you click on 'add to cart' you call a function checkEquipmentInCart() if the equipment you are trying to add is already there, you just change whatever you need to change;

Comment: Then what is your question. u tried something whats problem in it?

Comment: I have not tried it yet.  I'm not entirely sure how to write the code.